# aggregate by count of text by groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr

```
mydata=structure(list(id = c(123L, 123L, 124L, 124L), text = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("bad", "good", "I love u", "u bad"), class = "factor"), 
    group_id = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I want count how much texts for each id in each group.
For example. for id=123 in group_id=11 only 2 text phrases,
and for id=123 in group_id=11 also only 2 text phrases.
So as output i want

```
id  text    group_id
123  2        11
124  2        11
```

i use `q=aggregate(data$text, by=list(Category=data$group_id), FUN=sum)`

but i didn't get needed result

How can i get results?

Comment: Are you just looking for `table(mydata$id, mydata$group_id)` ?

Comment: You used the `dplyr` tag, so maybe this `library(dplyr); mydata %>% group_by(id, group_id) %>% summarise(text = n_distinct(text))`? (if you need distinct).

Comment: @s_t a simpler approach may be: `mydata %>% count(id, group_id)`

Comment: @Ali nice, I would recommend it if distinct's not needed. OP does not stated it (neither distinct clearly) so I think both solution can be used.

Comment: @s_t, one question, suppose id=123 has 10 rows,but only in 2 rows there are texts. 8 rows are empty. But how can i summarize not only texts rows, but empty rows too. I.E. in output  id=123, text=10

Comment: In that case, you could simply count the rows.

Answer (score 1):

What is your expected output?

you could use this which returns a list by `group_id` (I assume there is more than just `group_id=11`).

```
lapply(split(mydata,mydata$group_id), function(x) table(x$id))

$`11`

123 124 
  2   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you want:

```
tapply(mydata$text, mydata$id, function(x) sum(table(x)))
123 124 
  2   2
```

Is it this?